# What does the little pen icon mean in Trello?

Tags: trello

Sorry  to bother but I can not figure what is the "little pen icon" means exactly. Does someone knows ?

Comment: Could you maybe upload a screen shot for some context?

Comment: I was talking about this [pen icon](https://img.skitch.com/20111003-p988f14j6wrxgm8fumsaa32mhw.png) in the cards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that someone has added a description to the card